# Telegram bot: using path to Excel in host PythonAnyWhere for Python file

Tags: python, excel, telegram-bot, pythonanywhere

I am a beginner in Telegram bot development. I have written code where I send messages from an Excel file based on the received messages. Here is the code to load the Excel file on my laptop:

pythoncode
excel_file_path = "C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Project.xlsx"
excel_data = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name=excel_sheet_name)

I have deployed the bot on the PythonAnywhere hosting. Could you please guide me on how to correctly specify the file path or provide a web URL?

My code should work on PythonAnywhere hosting

Comment: Voting to close. This submission doesn’t meet multiple standards for quality on this site. Please read [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.